# What is causing the following stackoverflow error in a spring boot application with a scheduler?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, threadpool, spring-scheduled

**The issue happened in production and need an immediate fix. Please help me**

I have a spring boot application which is dockerized and running on an ec2 instance. Today the application started giving java.lang.StackOverflowError: null error suddenly without even making any changes.

The stack trace is attached below

[image: Stack Trace]

So in the stack trace you can see coffeejms-4, That is nothing but a thread's name. So issue happened within a thread that is running a scheduled job in my spring boot application.

The scheduler configuration is attached below

[image: Scheduler Config]

I don't know what caused this all of a sudden. I just restarted my docker container. I didn't change the image at all. I have tried following things

1. Restarted docker service
2. Restarted my ec2 instance
3. Assigned more memory for the spring boot app

But nothing is helping it. If someone could help me with this as soon as possible that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See this answer:
[Spring Boot StackOverFlowError : Null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67965661/spring-boot-stackoverflowerror-null)

I had the same error when we had a @Data annotation on an entity, which only resulted in an overflow error when the logger tried to log an error having to do with that entity.